# Running Wildfly in Eclipse Mars causing an error

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, wildfly-9

```
23:26:11,838 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([

    ("subsystem" => "ejb3"),
    ("service" => "remote")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.ejb3.connector is missing 

[jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector]"]}

23:26:11,883 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) 

WFLYCTL0183: Service status report

WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:

      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql-connector-java-5_1_6_jar (missing) 

dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:/IncidentManagerDS, service 

jboss.driver-demander.java:/IncidentManagerDS] 

      service jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-

connector (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb3.connector] 

WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service 

jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service 

jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener

23:26:11,974 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http 

management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management

23:26:11,974 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin

 console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990

23:26:11,975 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly

 Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) started (with errors) in 2555ms -

 Started 193 of 382 services (10 services failed or missing dependencies, 210 

services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Some jars are missing in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you pasted a configuration snippet to your `WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` and forgot to put the driver into classpath.

You can try one of these two options:

1. Your can put the JAR with MySQL driver (e.g. `mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar`) to `WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/deployments` like you would deploy WAR.
2. You can create a module in `WILDFLY_HOME/modules` with driver in it, for details see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Then you can refer to the driver in your datasources configuration or persistence.xml

Excerpt from standalone.xml, referring to driver deployed into deployments dir.

```
    <datasource ...>
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver>
        ...
    </datasource>
```

Excerpt from standalone.xml, referring to driver as a module.

```
    <datasources>
        <datasource ...>
            <driver>mysqljdbc</driver>
            ...
        </datasource>

        <drivers>
            <driver name="mysqljdbc" module="com.mysql.jdbc">
                 <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
```

Anyway, this problem is not related to Eclipse Mars IDE, the server won't start even when run from command line.